# I need to take the odd numbers out of a line of numbers. Using c++

Tags: c++

I tried to take odd numbers out of a line of numbers but my code freezes. I don't get it why.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main () {
    int number, k=0;
    cout << "enter the numbers: ";
    cin >> number;
    while(number!=0)
        k=number%10;
        if(k%2!=0)
            cout<<k<<" ";
        number=number/10;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to take odd numbers out of a line of numbers but my code freezes. I don't get it why.

Comment: You're missing `{}` around the body of the `while`. So the body of the loop is just the one `k=` statement and it never terminates.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/8nb3eqE1s <- if you enable warnings, the compiler will tell you something similar

Comment: Always enable compiler warnings, and pay attention to them.

Comment: In a word: C++ is not Python.

Comment: *I don't get it why* -- Do not use other programming languages as models in learning how to write C++ code.   If you continue to do this, you will end up with 1) Buggy programs, 2) Inefficient programs, and 3) Programs that look weird to a C++ programmer.  Your attempt of trying to use python rules in C++ resulted in 1) and 3) in happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem was that you did not use curly braces for the while loop, so the Loop was considering only the first line after the while as a statement of it so the loop was infinity, here is the solution:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main () {
    int number, k;
    cout << "enter the numbers: ";
    cin >> number;
    while(number != 0){
        k = number % 10;
        if(k % 2 != 0)
            cout<<k<<" ";
        number /= 10;
    }
    return 0;
}
```